# Sql Full-Text Query Expression, How to know which forms of synonyms match by sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, full-text-search, search-engine

I am using `Sql Full-Text Query expression` to find out the inflectional word from given table.
My sql query are look like

```
select * from Production.Product where CONTAINS(*,'FORMSOF(inflectional,"Tour")');
```

It works fine, and got desired result from table as shown in bellow image

[image]

Now result comes with `Touring` as Inflectional word of `Tour`.

My problem is , i want to know that which are inflectional word match by sql search engine.

Is there any way that sql give me list of Inflectional word match by search engine?

Something like this or any other way,

[image]

Let me know, or suggest me the changes i need to make in sql.

Please update the post if i miss something to be mention here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sys.dm_fts_parser` to expand the `formsof`, resulting in a full list of the words that are being matched by the full-text engine.

```
select display_term from sys.dm_fts_parser('formsof(inflectional, "Tour")',1031,0,0)
```